# Getting Relationship Object in coredata

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, stackmob, iphonecoredatarecipes

I am new to coredata, this is the 1st time i am using so please bear me as i am expalining.
i have 2 Entites named userinfo and usergroups, and they both are related in one to many relationship, Now usergroups(relationshipped name ) field wiil be created in userinfo. And Userinfo has also to many relationship to Usercontacts

Userinfo contains dateofbirth;email;firstname;lastname;password;salutation;userinfoId;username(user contact number);zipcode;
usergroups;usercontacts;

Usercontacts contains contactdescription;name;phone(conatct list of users);usercontacts_id;userinfo;

Usergroups containsgroupname;mobile_contacts;mobile_number;usergroups_id;userinfo_group;

I am able to get usergroups object for a particular username(which is unique in userinfo entity), For a particular mobile_contacts(in usergoups Entity) can i get the related name from the Userconatcts Entity.

I was trying like this

```
   NSString *usermobileNumber = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"UserNumber"];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Userinfo" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSPredicate *datapredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"username == %@",usermobileNumber];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:datapredicate];

[context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest onSuccess:^(NSArray *results){
    NSLog(@"results %@",[[results valueForKey:@"usergroups"] objectAtIndex:0]);

    for (NSString *order in results) {
        for (Usergroups *unit in [order usergroups]) {
            NSLog(@"%@", unit);
        }
    }
    [fetchRequest release];
}onFailure:^(NSError *error){
    NSLog(@"error %@",error);
}];
```

Any kind of suggestions or help would make me move my work
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as iterating over the relationship:

```
for (Userconatcts *contact in unit.mobile_contacts) {
    NSString *name = contact.name;
}
```

Comment: StackMob doesn't seem to include related objects by default when running a fetch request.  I'm interested if anyone has come up with a solution to this problem